# Draw Every pixel of path with different different color

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw

I want to draw a path of drawing. What i want that when i draw path , every pixel of my drawing path is drawn with different different color like chosen form array of colors . Please give me idea .

my code look like this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cappedPointerCount; i++) {
            if (mFingerPaths[i] != null) {
                int index = event.findPointerIndex(i);
                if (isSetRanbow) {
                    cor.setColor(mColors[random.nextInt(mColors.length)]);
                }
                mFingerPaths[i].lineTo(event.getX(index), event.getY(index));

                ///mFingerPaths[i].computeBounds(mPathBounds, true);
                if (isSetRanbow) {
                     drawCanvas.drawPoint(event.getX(index),
                     event.getY(index), cor);
cor);
                } else {
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(mFingerPaths[i], cor);
                }

                invalidate();
            }
        }
```

Comment: please explain more about your problem. whats the meaning of different color?

Comment: Actually I want to draw a line of many color(like random one  i.e. red green , blue etc). What I want is that every pixel of line is drawn with random color

Comment: From the code, it seems you are on the right track. What problems do you have with this code?

Comment: I have problem that when I am drawing points very fast then line  paint seems like confetti. I want a continuous line